# interfacing a 8051 to a altera de1 board

Tags: fpga, embedded

I am an undergraduate student. I am currently working on a project on implementing a fft core on an fpga and using it to do the calculations for a microcontroller 8051. The problem i am facing is that i have no clue how to go with the interfacing of the 8051 with altera de1( this is the fpga i am using).

Any kind of suggestion or reference to some reading material will be highly appreciated. 
thank you...

shaheel

Comment: The DE1 is the board you are using, not the FPGA!

Comment: The DE1 doesn't have an 8051, so it has to connect via the connectors.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dual-port RAM on the Altera as a data buffer. Hook one port directly to the 8051's external memory bus (it has one, right?) and interface it with the 8051's bus. Your FFT logic will access the RAM internally through the other port.

Then define two more pins to the Altera: one as a GO_n pin, where pulling the pin low will start the FFT of the buffered data (hook this up to an 8051 general-purpose output pin), and the other as a DONE_n pin, hooked up to an interrupt input pin on the 8051.

Then, to do an FFT, you do the following on the 8051:

1. Copy the FFT time data into the buffer.
2. Enable the interrupt that DONE_n is connected to.
3. Pulse GO_n low.
4. When the interrupt happens, the interrupt handler should notify your main program that the FFT is done (usually by setting a flag) and disabling the interrupt pin connected to DONE_n.
5. Main program eventually sees the flag, copies the frequency data from the buffer, and clears the flag.
6. ???
7. Profit!